# What are the disadvantages of Fibonacci Heaps?

Tags: algorithms, heaps, priority-queues

A [Fibonacci heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) is a data structure for priority queue / heap operations. It seems to have the best complexity for all operations:

[image]

Since it has the best performance, why not use it everywhere?
What are the disadvantages of it?

Comment: Those are asymptotic orders of growth of the number of operations (some of them of the expected value of the number of steps) in terms of the size of the input. They are not exact number of operations, or even estimations that give information for all values of $n$. From that information alone you cannot deduce that for a particular value of $n$ or for a fixed collection of values of $n$ one is faster than the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$O(1)$ merely means that no matter how large your heap grows, the operation will always take roughly the same time to execute. It doesn't mean "the fastest".

Wikipedia article you linked has section named "Practical considerations":

> Fibonacci heaps have a reputation for being slow in practice due to
> large memory consumption per node and high constant factors on all
> operations. Recent experimental results suggest that Fibonacci heaps
> are more efficient in practice than most of its later derivatives,
> including quake heaps, violation heaps, strict Fibonacci heaps, rank
> pairing heaps, but less efficient than either pairing heaps or
> array-based heaps.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit cheating to call insert and decrease-key O(1), because the implementation is incredibly lazy. The insert and decrease-key increase the entropy of the heap (makes it more messy). Instead of rebalancing immediately (which would make it O(log n)), it procrastinates until delete-min is called, which makes that operation more expensive. It's almost like the Fibonacci heap was invented for the sole purpose of looking good on a time complexity table like that!

So yes, consecutive calls to insert and decrease-key are technically O(1), but it results in mounting debt that you'll have to repay at some point. Since delete-min is the entire point of the priority que, you can't really avoid it. Therefore overall it's not necessarily going to have better performance than alternatives. In fact, it could even be outperformed by non-heap alternatives such as take-min operation on a binary tree.

The O(log n) listed for delete-min is amortized complexity, not worst case complexity. A disadvantage is that due to buildup of entropy/debt as described above, the actual cost of a given call could be as much as O(n). Another disadvantage of the Fibonacci heap is that it uses more memory per element than alternatives like binary heap.

Comment: I think one case where Fibonacci heaps would be better is if you have an algorithm that does lots and lots of decrease-key operations and a relatively small number of delete-min operations.  Then your criticism is not valid -- it doesn't result in mounting debt you can't avoid.

Comment: @D.W. In such case you'd have lots of O(1) decrease-key, and a few O(n) delete-min. You pay for the O(1) on insert and decrease-key by making the next call to delete-min more expensive.

My criticism is that delete-min is the whole point of the data structure. Nobody is going to get any practical use out of it without calling delete-min.

Comment: That's not correct.  delete-min takes $O(\log n)$ time, not $O(n)$.   No one is suggesting there will be applications where delete-min is never called.  Rather, I think there might be applications that call decrease-key lots of times, and delete-min a few times.  For those applications, the Fibonacci heap might be better, and your criticism is not applicable.

Comment: @D.W. If you called lots of insert and/or decrease-key, then the next call to delete-min becomes very expensive since it has to rebalance, which could be as much as O(N) in worst case. This is where you pay for the debt of procrastinating on rebalancing. Once balanced, consecutive calls to delete-min take O(log(N)).

Comment: I'm referring to amortized running time.  Any sequence of $A$ decrease-key operations and $B$ delete-min operations will take $O(A + B \log n)$ time, with a Fibonacci heap.  Compare this to $O(A \log n + B \log n)$ time, for a standard heap.  Therefore, if $A \gg B$, then Fibonacci heaps might be faster than standard heaps.  In particular, your conclusions are not valid for all applications.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap.

Comment: @D.W. "Therefore, if A≫B, then Fibonacci heaps might be faster than standard heaps." 

That's exactly the wrong conclusion. For A decrease-key followed by B delete-min, the decrease-key operations add up to workload C0 * A, and the B delete-min operations add up to workload C1 * (A + log(N)) + C2 * (B - 1) * log(N); (that's one expensive delete-min followed by multiple cheap delete-min).

It is if delete-min is called reasonably frequently, that it keeps the heap balanced and gets the O(log(N)). If A >> B, then the performance of delete-min gets worse, with roughly O((A / B)) performance.

Comment: That doesn't look right to me.  That looks to me like it contradicts the amortized running times listed in standard textbooks and in Wikipedia.  Are you arguing that all of those standard resources are wrong?  That seems like it needs some justification (in your answer).  I suspect there is a misunderstanding somewhere.  Are you familiar with amortized running time analysis?

Comment: @D.W. The difference is that I'm looking at the actual complexity rather than the amortized complexity. Notice that in my analysis, it still comes down to roughly the O(A + B * log(N)) you mentioned. However, in my analysis, part of that O(A) happens not in decrease-key, but in delete-min. This supports my point, that if A/B is the ratio of calls to decrease-key versus delete-min, the higher that ratio, the worse the overall performance of delete-min gets. The fibonacci heap's overall performance doesn't necessarily improve relative to other data structures by increasing the ratio A/B.

Comment: I think it's a little bit misleading to say that delete-min becomes expensive.  One delete-min becomes more expensive, but when taken in context of all of the operations, it can still be better than a standard heap, because the speedups outweigh the slowdowns.  It's not the case that Fibonacci heap only looks good on the table, or that it was invented only for that purpose - it also leads to better total running time for some algorithms.